# Ionic - Xcode archive error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods

I'm trying generate the build of an Ionic ios application, however, when I try archive in Xcode I'm getting the following error:

```
Ld /Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/brazil-cartoon.build/Release-iphoneos/brazil-cartoon.build/Objects-normal/armv7/brazil-cartoon normal armv7
cd /Users/huroapps/Documents/brazil-cartoon-app/platforms/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk -L/Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/huroapps/Documents/brazil-cartoon-app/platforms/ios/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework -Fbrazil-cartoon/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4 -Fbrazil-cartoon/Plugins/cordova-plugin-googleplus -filelist /Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/brazil-cartoon.build/Release-iphoneos/brazil-cartoon.build/Objects-normal/armv7/brazil-cartoon.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/brazil-cartoon.build/Release-iphoneos/brazil-cartoon.build/Objects-normal/armv7/brazil-cartoon_lto.o -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -framework OneSignal -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UserNotifications /Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a -weak_framework ImageIO -framework CoreLocation -framework AVFoundation -framework Bolts -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework GoogleAppUtilities -framework GoogleAuthUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities -framework GoogleSignIn -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -weak_framework AddressBook -weak_framework CoreText -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework Security -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -weak-lz -weak-lz -weak_framework WebKit -weak_framework Social -weak_framework MessageUI -lPods-brazil-cartoon -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/brazil-cartoon.build/Release-iphoneos/brazil-cartoon.build/Objects-normal/armv7/brazil-cartoon_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/huroapps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brazil-cartoon-hjdhkgzminpyprhlbjaopuxmmsve/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/brazil-cartoon/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/brazil-cartoon.build/Release-iphoneos/brazil-cartoon.build/Objects-normal/armv7/brazil-cartoon

ld: library not found for -lPods-brazil-cartoon 
clang: error: linker     command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The name of the application is brazil-cartoon and it appears Xcode can't find some project file. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are opening the `.xcworkspace` and not the `.xcodeproj`

Make sure you have [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) installed

If you are opening the `.xcworkspace` and have CocoaPods installed, then try to navigate to `projectName/platforms/ios/` in the terminal and run `pod install` and then build again.